# Curve Plotting in Python

Tags: python, graph, spyder, physics, curve

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcomP.png)
[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ncz.png)

I've been trying to obtain the output as shown above, however, I can't seem to figure out the code to get the x-axis. Supposedly, the curve of P(r) is 0 when r/a_0 = 2 but my output is slightly off. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

e_0 = 8.85418782e-12 #permittivity of free space in F/m
h = 1.05457182e-34 #reduced Planck's constant in Js
m_e = 9.10938370e-31 #electron rest mass in kg
e = 1.60217663e-19 #elementary charge in C

def wf_2s(r, args):
    a_0 = args
    return (1/((4 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi ) * a_0**(3/2)))) * (2 - (r/a_0)) * np.exp(-r/(2*a_0))

def P(r, args):
    a_0 = args
    return (4 * np.pi * r**2 * (np.abs(wf_2s(r, a_0)))**2)

a_0 = (4 * np.pi * e_0 * h**2)/(m_e * e**2)
args = a_0

ri = 0; rl = 2 * a_0

xarr = np.linspace(ri, rl, 500)
yarr = P(xarr, args)
ymin = min(yarr); ymax = max(yarr);

Np = 10000
count = 0
inside = {}
for i in range(Np):
    xrand = random.uniform(ri, rl)
    yrand = random.uniform(ymin, ymax)
    y = P(xrand, args)
    if P(xrand, args) > 0 and yrand >= 0 and yrand < P(xrand, args):
        count = count + 1
        inside[count] = [xrand, yrand]
    elif P(xrand, args) < 0 and yrand <= 0 and yrand >= P(xrand, args):
        count = count + 1
        inside[count] = [xrand, yrand]
    else:
        zero = 0

Lx = rl - ri;
Ly = ymax - ymin
A = Lx * Ly
I = (count/Np) * A

print('Np, c =', Np, count)
print('I =', I)

#(ii)
listiv = list(inside.values())
xiarr = [i[0] for i in listiv]
yiarr = [i[1] for i in listiv]

plt.plot(xarr, yarr)
plt.scatter(xiarr, yiarr, s=0.5)
plt.plot(xarr, [P(r, a_0) for r in xarr])
ri = 0; rl = 6 * a_0
args = a_0

xarr2 = np.linspace(ri, rl, 1000)
yarr2 = P(xarr2, args)
plt.plot(xarr2, yarr2)
```

and my output is:
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7a8V.png)

Comment: Could it be that you just have to divide your x-axis by the Bohr radius a0 to solve the problem?